# Selecting a cluster based on minimum average distance

Tags: clustering

I have a symmetric matrix of non-Euclidean distances of size $N$ (say, 500) and I would like to select one cluster of a fixed size $K$ (say, 25), so that it has the smallest average distance within this cluster. What is a good algorithm for doing that given combinatorial complexity of the problem?

Currently I have implemented the following algorithm, which is not perfect in finding the optimum:

1. Take $K$ points at random, form the cluster
2. Find $K$ points
   with smallest average distance to the points in the cluster at
   step 1). Call these $K$ points the new cluster
3. Repeat 1) and 2) until selected $K$ points are the same in both steps or until the
   new cluster has the larger average distance than the old cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're re-inventing the [k-means algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) that has been here for a while ([Lloyd's algorithm from 1957](https://cs.nyu.edu/~roweis/csc2515-2006/readings/lloyd57.pdf)). Although the problem normally minimizes Euclidean distances, it shouldn't be a problem as long as your distance function is a [metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)).

[k-means++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means%2B%2B) due to careful seeding provides more stable results in less iterations ([original paper](http://ilpubs.stanford.edu:8090/778/1/2006-13.pdf)).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It applies well to the problem with one exception. What I aim to find is just one optimal cluster with minimum distance, whereas k-means and k-means++ would minimize the sum of distances over all clusters. Are you aware of a modification for k-means or separate algorithms in which we just aim to find one cluster with minimum within distance?